# Registering classes to factory with classes in different files

Tags: python, factory-pattern

I have a factory as shown in the following code:

```
class ClassFactory:
    registry = {}

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, name):
        def inner_wrapper(wrapped_class):
            if name in cls.registry:
                print(f'Class {name} already exists. Will replace it')
            cls.registry[name] = wrapped_class
            return wrapped_class
    return inner_wrapper

    @classmethod
    def create_type(cls, name):
        exec_class = cls.registry[name]
        type = exec_class()
        return type


@ClassFactory.register('Class 1')
class M1():
    def __init__(self):
       print ("Starting Class 1")


@ClassFactory.register('Class 2')
class M2():
    def __init__(self):
       print("Starting Class 2")
```

This works fine and when I do

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(ClassFactory.registry.keys())
    foo = ClassFactory.create_type("Class 2")
```

I get the expected result of `dict_keys(['Class 1', 'Class 2']) Starting Class 2`

Now the problem is that I want to isolate classes M1 and M2 to their own files m1.py and m2.py, and in the future add other classes using their own files in a plugin manner.
However, simply placing it in their own file
m2.py

```
from test_ import ClassFactory
@MethodFactory.register('Class 2')
class M2():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Starting Class 2")
```

gives the result `dict_keys(['Class 1'])` since it never gets to register the class.

So my question is: How can I ensure that the class is registered when placed in a file different from the factory, without making changes to the factory file whenever I want to add a new class? How to self register in this way? Also, is this decorator way a good way to do this kind of thing, or are there better practices?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure you need to go through this much trouble. A simple `dict` would suffice: `d = {'Class 1': M1, 'Class 2': M2}`, followed by `foo = d['Class1']()`. The *implementation* of patterns can vary greatly between languages, depending on what features a particular language provides. The ability to use functions and classes as first-class values in Python makes many patterns trivial bordering on unnecessary.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this OP ?

Comment: @cryp not really, since it was a low priority task I never got around to continua a search for solution.

Comment: @RNunes TY !
Also do you why this happens ? Having everything in one file works while splitting out into individual modules doenst ?

Comment: @cryp My guess is python doesn't understand that the file exists and thus never registers the class. 
I think this can probably be solved by forcing a read of the file, by loading all files in the form mx.py in the directory or something like that. Hope this helps, and if you solve it, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I ensure that the class is registered when placed in a file different from the factory, without making changes to the factory file whenever I want to add a new class?

I'm playing around with a similar problem, and I've found a possible solution. It seems too much of a 'hack' though, so set your critical thinking levels to 'high' when reading my suggestion below :)

As you've mentioned in one of your comments above, the trick is to force the loading of the individual *`.py` files that contain individual class definitions.

Applying this to your example, this would involve:

1. Keeping all class implementations in a specific folders, e.g., structuring the files as follows:

```
.
└- factory.py     # file with the ClassFactory class
└─ classes/
  └- __init__.py
  └- m1.py        # file with M1 class
  └- m2.py        # file with M2 class
```

2. Adding the following statement to the end of your `factory.py` file, which will take care of loading and registering each individual class:

```py
from classes import *
```

3. Add a piece of code like the snippet below to your `__init__.py` within the `classes/` foder, so that to dynamically load all classes [[1]](https://julienharbulot.com/python-dynamical-import.html):

```py
from inspect import isclass
from pkgutil import iter_modules
from pathlib import Path
from importlib import import_module

# iterate through the modules in the current package
package_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
for (_, module_name, _) in iter_modules([package_dir]):

    # import the module and iterate through its attributes
    module = import_module(f"{__name__}.{module_name}")
    for attribute_name in dir(module):
        attribute = getattr(module, attribute_name)

        if isclass(attribute):            
            # Add the class to this package's variables
            globals()[attribute_name] = attribute
```

If I then run your test code, I get the desired result:

```py
# test.py

from factory import ClassFactory

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(ClassFactory.registry.keys())
    foo = ClassFactory.create_type("Class 2")
```

```
$ python test.py
dict_keys(['Class 1', 'Class 2'])
Starting Class 2
```

> Also, is this decorator way a good way to do this kind of thing, or are there better practices?

Unfortunately, I'm not experienced enough to answer this question. However, when searching for answers to this problem, I've came across the following sources that may be helpful to you:

- [[2]](https://effectivepython.com/2015/02/02/register-class-existence-with-metaclasses) : this presents a method for registering class existence based on Python Metaclasses. As far as I understand, it relies on the registering of **subclasses**, so I don't know how well it applies to your case. I did not follow this approach, as I've noticed that the new edition of the book suggests the use of another technique (see bullet below).
- [[3]](https://effectivepython.com/), item 49 : this is the 'current' suggestion for subclass registering, which relies on the definition of the `__init_subclass__()` function in a base class.

If I had to apply the `__init_subclass__()` approach to your case, I'd do the following:

1. Add a `Registrable` base class to your `factory.py` (and slightly re-factor `ClassFactory`), like this:

```py
class Registrable:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, name:str):
        ClassFactory.register(name, cls)

class ClassFactory:
    registry = {}

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, name:str, sub_class:Registrable):
        if name in cls.registry:
             print(f'Class {name} already exists. Will replace it')
        cls.registry[name] = sub_class

    @classmethod
    def create_type(cls, name):
        exec_class = cls.registry[name]
        type = exec_class()
        return type

from classes import *
```

2. Slightly modify your concrete classes to inherit from the `Registrable` base class, e.g.:

```py
from factory import Registrable

class M2(Registrable, name='Class 2'):
    def __init__(self):
       print ("Starting Class 2")
```

Comment: Looks like I have to take a look at subclasses when I go back to a similar problem. 
Looks like you have this covered, even if its a "hack". I'm marking as solved.
Hey @cryp, take a look at this!